# scmCommentPrefix line feeds

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to get the scmCommentPrefix working as per the documentation at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#scmCommentPrefix

The problem is that whatever prefix you add is concantenated to the various release plugin comments without a space, so if I have scmCommentPrefix=ABCD-123, then the resulting comments look like (from my dryRun attempt):

```
[INFO] Full run would be checking in 3 files with message: 'ABCD-123prepare for
next development iteration'
```

The documentation mentions you can add a line break to the prefix with "ALT 10" or "ALT 13" - can someone give me a working example?  Because if I add either of those string within quotes, they are added literally, and if I omit the quotes I get a maven error complaining about an invalid goal of ALT.

Answer (score 5):

For whitespace, enclose the argument in double quotes, e.g. `-DscmCommentPrefix="ABCD-123 "` .  Note the space before the second double quote.

Does `-DscmCommentPrefix="ABCD-123\n"` work for the newlines?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ${line.separator} for newline.
e.q.

```
-DscmCommentPrefix="ABCD-123${line.separator}
```

See comment https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-156

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `xml:space="preserve"` as property attribute.
Here is plugin configuration example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- ... -->
    <configuration>
        <scmCommentPrefix xml:space="preserve">ABCD-123 </scmCommentPrefix>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution for those of us wanting to use the pom.xml. Just tested and working great. Thank you.